# Wix installer bundle error with DirectX 9

Tags: wix, directx, directx-9

I'm trying to create a wix bundle installer that will install some pre-reqs with my application.  On some computers (not all) I'm getting an error when installing the DirectX 9 pre-req.  The error I'm getting is this...

> Applying execute package: DirectX9c, action: Install, path:
>   C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache\3C8243734CF43DD7BB2332BA05B58CCACFA4377C\dxwebsetup.exe,
>   arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache\3C8243734CF43DD7BB2332BA05B58CCACFA4377C\dxwebsetup.exe" /Q'
>   Error 0xfffffff7: Process returned error: 0xfffffff7
>   Error 0xfffffff7: Failed to execute EXE package.
>   Error 0xfffffff7: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
>   Applied execute package: DirectX9c, result: 0xfffffff7, restart: None
>   Error 0xfffffff7: Failed to execute EXE package.

I have read that this error code 0xfffffff7 possibly means DirectX is already installed or a higher version is installed.  How to I tell WIX to ignore this error code because it is out of bounds of a max int.  I think this is the max value of an unsigned int.

Here is my code for the exepackage

```
  <ExePackage Id="DirectX9c"
              SourceFile="..\Assets\dxwebsetup.exe"
              InstallCommand="/Q">
    <ExitCode Value="0" Behavior="success"/>
  </ExePackage>
```

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/exitcode.html

Value is an integer type so I can't put 0xfffffff7 or 4294967287

Comment: First, make sure you read [Not So Direct Setup](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/09/08/not-so-direct-setup.aspx) in detail to make sure you understand what this thing actually does and more importantly does not install. Second, make sure you are using the April 2011 refresh of the DXSETUP bits (see [web](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/11/30/dxwebsetup-update.aspx) and [standalone](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2011/04/19/dxsetup-update.aspx)).

Comment: Third, technically ``DXWEBSETUP.EXE`` isn't a file you can redistribute with your app per the DirectX SDK EULA. If you identify what it is your program *actually* needs, then you can make small package using ``DXSETUP.EXE`` that just installs whatever it is your application is really using. You probably need one version of D3DX9 and that's it for example since DirectX 9.0c itself has been part of the OS since Windows XP Service Pack 2.

Comment: The reason I started using the web installer in the first place was because it was much simpler.  The component of my app that requires DirectX is a third party imaging library that the developers have stopped responding and I do not know what parts of DirectX they are using.  Is there a dependency walking tool I can use to see what I need from DirectX and only package that?

Comment: If you are using a 3rd party DLL, then open a Visual Studio Command Prompt and type: ``dumpbin /imports filename.dll``. If you are using a static library, run the same command on your EXE. It will dump out each DLL it uses.

Comment: Thank you for you help Chuck.  I found the issue... this app is using the managed directx libraries which i finally got installed with dxsetup.exe.

Comment: Legacy Managed DirectX 1.1!?. Oh lord. See [DirectX and NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/12/09/directx-and-net.aspx).

Comment: Not sure if this helps but the error value of 0xfffffff7 is the _signed decimal_ **-9** (not 4294967287). I had a similar issue where my Inno Setup installer triggers a DirectX install, but exists with the error -9 since the latest DirectX is already installed (and consequently the DirectX installer was exited 'by the user' - programmatically)